# How to access functions of a controller from within another controller via scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have the following problem, I want to call a function of another controller from within a controller I want to use for a guided tour (I'm using ngJoyRide for the tour). The function I want to call in the other controller is so to say a translator (LanguageController), which fetches a string from a database according to the key given as parameter. The LanguageController will, if the key is not found, return an error that the string could not be fetched from the database. In my index.html fetching the string works, but I want to use it in the overlay element of my guided tour, which does not work, but only shows the "not fetched yet"-error of the LanguageController.

My index.html looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-controller="LangCtrl as lc" >
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl as uc" mail='@email' firstname='@firstname'>
        <div ng-controller="GuidedTourCtrl as gtc">
            <div ng-joy-ride="startJoyRide" config="config" on-finish="onFinish()"  on-skip="onFinish()">
              ...
              <a href="/#/language/create" class="font-white"> {{lc.getTerm('system_lang_edit')}} </a>
              ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The controller I'm using for the guided Tour looks like this:

```
guidedTourModule.controller('GuidedTourCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.startJoyRide = false;
        this.start = function () {
            $scope.startJoyRide = true;
        }

        $scope.config = [
            {
                type: "title",
                ...
            },
            {
                type: "element",
                selector: "#groups",
                heading: "heading",
                text:   "   <div id='title-text' class='col-md-12'>\
                                <span class='main-text'>"\
                                     + $scope.lc.getTerm('system_navi_messages') + "\
                                    text text text text\
                                </span>\
                                <br/>\
                                <br/>\
                            </div>",
                placement: "right",
                scroll: true,
                attachToBody: true
            }
        ];
        ...
}]);
```

And the output I ultimately get looks like this for the overlay element:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="pop-over-text" class="col-md-12">  
        <div id='title-text' class='col-md-12'>                                
            <span class='main-text'>
                not fetched yet: system_navi_messages                                        
                text text text text                             
            </span>                             
            <br/>                               
            <br/>                           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I hope someone can see the error in my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: communicate using `$broadcast` or using service

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a very common question that boils down to "How to communicate between controllers".

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Maybe you can also give me a little bit insight as to why I am able to access the LanguageController? This seems to be possible, since the error message is defined there, otherwise I would get a message like lc or getTerm is undefinded, wouldn't I?

Comment: It was possible to communicate the way I did in my original post. The only (dumb) issue was, that the LanguageController didn't have the language keys and values buffered at the time I accessed them.

Answer (score 0):

Things needs clarity are,

How you defined the 'getTerm' function in your Language controller, either by using **this.getTerm()** or **$scope.getTerm()**. Since you are using alias name you will be having this.getTerm in Language controller.

Reason why you are able to access the getTerm function in your overlay element is, since this overlay element is inside the parent controller(Language Controller) and you are referencing it with alias name **'lc'** while calling the getTerm function. Thats' why it is accessible.
But the string you pass as a *parameter is not reachable to the parent* controller. that's why the error message is rendered in the overlay HTML.

Please make a **plunker** of your app, so that will be helpful to answer your problem.

Comment: But the parameter has to be reachable by the LanguageController. You weren't able to see this because I didn't add the LanguageController to my post, but since the error message showed the parameter correctly, the LanguageController received it correctly.

I was able to correct my application however. The error was really dumb, the keys and values of the languageController weren't buffered at the time I accessed them.